# Question of under review -situation

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

I  would be happy to have a short comment by somebody on following simple situation: I submitted my paper in beginning of January. In the end or January the status changed from the administration (Editor) to "under review". After that, this has not changed, it is still "under review". Is this normal. My field is history.

The journal doesn't indicate the review-times in the pages, but from the same publishing house's pages I have seen other journals of the same field and noted that the time may vary from 3-4 months up to one year.

I have decided that I will patiently wait, but I am starting to feel insecure about if they have forgotten to push the status-button. So, it would be nice just to know, does this sounds normal? Another article a couple of years ago in another journal didn't take that long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time frame you mention is within what can be encountered. The time frames also differ wide between disciplines but also from journal to journal so one way to check how reasonable it is will be to check the journal for how long it has taken other papers to go through to acceptance. Many journals state this for each article and hopefully your journal does so as well. If no such information is stated you can try and ask a senior colleague who may have a perspective on the journals and their turn-over times.

Comment: Thank you very much. This particular journal doesnt state the acceptance time of papers, but the same publisher has equivalent journals where times are mentioned, so I will rely on information on those. I will continue to wait, thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your field, it may be acceptable to write a short note to the journal requesting an update on the status of the article.  So long as you are respectful in asking, there will not be any harm in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Since the time-frames for review in other journals under the same publisher vary anywhere between 3-4 months to a year, I think you can consider the time-frame normal in your case. However, I think it should be fine to write a polite email to the journal editor asking him/her to update you about the current status of your paper.