# What can cause the date of submission status to change without a change of status "under review" for Elsevier editorial systems?

Tags: publications, publishers, elsevier

I have a paper submitted to a journal of Elsevier.

From "Manuscript Submitted" to "with editor" took one day; then it was  "with editor" for five days, and then "under review". One and a half months later, the status of the paper was still "under review", but the date of status has changed.

What can cause the date in the submission system to change in the absence of a change in status?

Comment: Unfortunately it means nothing.

Comment: @StrongBad: Oh, maybe I did not make my intention clear enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question of under review -situation](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26049/question-of-under-review-situation)

Comment: @Kurt no I understood your question. The causes range all the way from something interesting happened with the progress of your manuscript to they rebooted the server.

Comment: @StrongBad: Ah I see; so spending time to guess is wasting time :)

Comment: @scaaahu: I do not see anywhere of this question making you vote to close :)

Comment: @scaaahu: Guess what? Just because something is insignificant to you does not necessarily mean that the thing is insignificant to others. Suggest you to think macroly.

Comment: I have nothing personally against you. The other question is a dup of this one, in my opinion. Both question have the situation "with editor" and then "under review" for a while. The only difference is that you name the publisher and the other one didn't which makes the other one more general than yours.

Comment: @scaaahu the questions seem different since in this question the status was recently updated (although not changed).

Comment: @StrongBad The OP of the other question commented that there was no time stamp of the status. To me, the spirit of the two are the same, like you said in the previous comment, it could be any reason.

Comment: I'd suggest you to write to the Elsevier support. Those status messages are quite opaque, and implementing a full "paper history" feature does not seem a daunting task. But if no one complains and submits bug reports, they will never have an incentive to change. If you know the editor or see him/her at a conference, you may consider pinging him/her about the issue, too.

Comment: One and a half months is not too long. If it stays like that for 6 months, then worry.

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, but my question is not about the length of time of being under review; it is about the changing of the date of status!

Comment: I know. And yet, from my experience (although not with Elsevier) it doesn't mean much. I doubt that your article was either accepted or rejected in five days (thus changing the status). It's probably a technical thing. If you're really nervous, just mail the editor or something, but take into consideration that an editor who gets mail like that feels like a parent with kids in the backseat asking "are we there yet?".

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, it must be the original statement of my question that confused you. I have edited it :)

Comment: I've had a similar experience with a Springer journal. As far as I can tell, whenever editor manages to find a reviewer, status changes to under review. This date change might have happened because he might have found the other reviewer(s) recently. Hope that helps. @Kurt

Comment: If you didn't sample the website too frequently, it's possible there was a status of 'with editor' for a day or two there. It can happen if the reviewers give back their reviews and the editor is still not satisfied (e.g. if there are two contradicting reviews, or if one declined). Since you sampled it, say, every few days, you just missed the status update and saw only the 'under review'. 
I once had this 'with editor' and 'under review' back and forth for some time, not just once (it wasn't with Elsevier, though).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a paper is assigned to a reviewer, the reviewer may decline or fail to review the paper.  In this case the editor will assign the paper to a new reviewer.  The status date will change at the day the new review was assigned, but the status will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But is the answer valid for my situation? I mean, would a reviewer decline to review a paper after one and a half month?

Comment: If it took that long, they probably just failed to submit a review.  We cannot be sure what happened in your situation without more information.

Comment: sometimes reviewers agree to review, but then fail to actually do so, as AnonymousPhysicist says. It's also possible that it has been sent to multiple potential reviewers, each about a week apart, and each of the first few declined to review, so it was sent on to another reveiwer. Or that it was sent to thr first batch of reviewers and the editor was slow to invite a new batch when the first declined. Or possibly, the date changed when the 1st review was submitted and you are still waiting on a 2nd or 3rd review.

Answer (score 4):

For that you need to know how the journal system works. When status is "with editor" it doesn't always implies that the paper is not send for reviews. Because in journals the configuration of online submission system is such that if at least 2 or 3 reviewers have accepted the review request only then status will change to "under review". Also when status is "under review" and status date is changing then it means the reviewers have submitted his/her report in the system (which have led to change in status date). When at least 2 or 3 reviewers reports (this count is configured by the journal) are not come till then status won't change. If they come then status may change to "with editor" or "under editor evaluation" or "required reviews completed". Under these status also the status date may change which implies remaining reviewer(s) have also submitted their reports.

Answer (score 2):

There could me multiple reasions for the status date to change:

- Reviewer comments are added to the database
- The reviewer changes
- Editor checks the database

See this question: http://www.editage.com/insights/why-does-the-status-date-of-a-submission-change-periodically-though-the-status-remains-unchanged